# Problem: linear form

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with this problem: we are on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we consider two non-null vectors, $ \vec{v}, \ \vec{w}$, and a non-trivial linear form $\phi\in{\mathbb{R}^2}^*$.  Now if  $\phi(\vec{v})=\phi(\vec{w})=0$ this check that have the vectors linear independence? and if $\phi(\vec{v})=\phi(\vec{w})=1$ have the vectors linear independence? please help!

Comment: Well, for ***any*** real coefficients $a,b,$ we get $\phi (a \vec{v} + b \vec{w}) = 0$

Comment: Well, since the kernel is a subspace, and it is at most 1-dimensional (otherwise the form is 0), aren't any two vectors in the kernel dependent? (Maybe that is what Will meant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\phi: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is a non-zero linear map, then its kernel is a one dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.

If $\phi(v) = \phi(w) = 0$, then both $v$ and $w$ lie in the kernel of $\phi$.  Since both vectors are in the same one-dimensional subspace, they are **not** linearly independent.

If we had $\phi(v) = \phi(w) = 1$, we could **not** immediately deduce whether or not $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent, since either could be true in this case.  However, if we had $\phi(v) = \phi(w) = 1$ **and** $v \neq w$, then we **can** say that $v$ and $w$ **are** linearly independent.

Comment: But, by rank-nullity, the complement of the kernel is also 1-dimensional.

Comment: @Gary. the two vectors don't necessarily lie in the *orthogonal* complement, if that's what you mean.  The *set*-complement of the kernel, on the other hand, is not a subspace.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the answer is no: if $\phi$ is a nonzero linear map, then its kernel may be 1-dimensional, in which case, any two vectors are dependent. And then the dimension of the image is also $1$, by rank-nullity, so , again, any two vectors are dependent.